# Formatting a jQuery control group widget

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery controlgroup widget which is comprised of 2 radio buttons. When I view this code on my mobile, the `Request Feature` half of the button wraps onto a second line, but the `Report Bug` half doesn't, which results in the bottom of the widget being uneven (see pic). Is there a way I can get around this?

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="halves" id="helpType">
    <input type="radio" name="helpSelector" id="helpBug" value="helpBug" />
    <label for="helpBug">Report Bug</label>
    <input type="radio" name="helpSelector" id="helpFeature" value="helpFeature" />
    <label for="helpFeature">Request Feature</label>
</fieldset>
```

1. I'm not keen to add a `<br />` tag between the words as then it'll wrap unnecessarily on larger screens.
2. I don't want to add a `white-space: nowrap;` style as I want the entire text shown and I would otherwise have to use a `text-overflow:` style.

[image]

Comment: You should adjust your css typography to your needs.

Comment: Not a bad idea @wscourge. Is there way to make the font size "as large as possible while still fitting on one line"?

Comment: I guess it is matter of trying and you can always adjust it somehow by hand using media-queries. If you paste your CSS code I can try doing so.

Comment: Thanks @wscourge. This seems a little clunky - how would it handle different screen sizes? And what about users who turn up the size of their text in accessibility? Or set it to bold? Maybe it would be easier to just set the height of them both to the height of the tallest side? How would I do that?

Comment: It is not a good idea to set fixed heights for your fonts. Common approach is to make fonts relative, using rem's, % or em's. I did not understand your question, what do you mean by "tallest side" ? Also, consider adding CSS to your question.

Comment: `display: table-cell` might help you, but it's hard to say without seeing your current CSS.

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't have any custom CSS for this currently, just vanilla jQuery Mobile CSS.

Comment: I've just added `#helpType div div .ui-btn { padding: .7em .5em !important; }` (jQuery mobile default is `.7em 1em`). This isn't a great fix.

Comment: Look into flexbox if you can afford the limited browser support. Otherwise you may have simulate a table to achieve this.

Comment: Never heard of flex box but it looks amazing!! Yes, limited browser support is fine so long at it works on Mobile Safari. Thanks @SeinopSys! Are you able to point me in the right direction getting started on Flexbox? Looks like there is a lot to learn!

Comment: @Brad Yes, use Google.